# Running django-pdb in post mortem mode for a test command

Tags: python, django, pdb

I'm trying to run a test suite using `python manage.py test`, but I run into an error which ends like this:

```
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "hstore" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "options" varchar(255)[] NOT NULL, "conditions" hstore NOT...
```

I'd like to drop into the debugger at this point in order to see the full `sql` statement. To this end, I've run `pip install django-pdb` and added the following lines to my `settings.py` (as per the [instructions](https://github.com/HassenPy/django-pdb)):

```
# Order is important and depends on your Django version.
# With Django 1.7+ put it towards the beginning, otherwise towards the end.
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_pdb',
    ...
)

# Make sure to add PdbMiddleware after all other middleware.
# PdbMiddleware only activates when settings.DEBUG is True.
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django_pdb.middleware.PdbMiddleware',
)
```

Then I try to re-run the test with the `--pm` option:

```
python manage.py test lucy_web.tests.notifications --pm
```

However, this is not recognized:

```
manage.py test: error: unrecognized arguments: --pm
```

I've also tried to run this command with `--ipdb` instead of `--pm`, but it seems to not work: I simply get an error message without dropping into the debugger. Any ideas what the issue might be? Is post mortem debugging perhaps not supported for `test` commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Django Running Test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests) you'll need to have the hstore extension enabled. Also running command 
options should be after the `test` command i.e.

`python manage.py test --pm lucy_web.tests.notifications`

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import HStoreExtension

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
...

    operations = [
        HStoreExtension(),
        ...
    ]
```